# Difference between business process and events in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Please help me understand the difference between business process and events in hybris. What is the advantage of using Business Process over events?

Comment: SAP Hybris is a subsidiary company, not a product. Which SAP Hybris product are you using specifically?

Comment: @Dai From the tag, he's referring to SAP Hybris (now known as SAP Commerce Cloud).

Answer (score 4):

The Hybris Process Engine is used for defining business processes. It is similar to a workflow (like a workflow diagram). It has a sequence/flow to be followed, and uses different kinds of nodes:

- Action: carry out process logic and permit alternative actions to be carried out
- Wait: wait for a subprocess or an external process result
- Notify: inform a user or user group of the state of a process
- Split: split the process into parallel paths
- End: end the process and store state in a process item

Hybris also has a Workflow System. It is different from the Process Engine, but conceptually the same and uses different classes.

Business Process does not have human intervention, but a Workflow can have.

On the other hand, the Event System is simply for receiving and sending events. It's similar to the Observer design pattern.

**OFFICIAL REFERENCES:**

- The SAP Commerce processengine: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8c30e9ae86691014a36ed5fd11e24a1e.html
- workflow Extension: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8c878e7286691014b3aaf108edc38cca.html
- Event System: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8bbbc04e866910149e93ca9faad254eb.html